# Dual boot with Windows 10 - Windows resolution stuck at 800x600

Tags: dual-boot, resolution

I installed elementary OS in my Asus Vivobook S15 with 2GB NVidia MX150.
Everything is well with elementary OS. But Windows - there is a problem.
If I change the UEFI settings for Windows Boot Manager, Windows 10 loads fine. But if I have Ubuntu boot manager selected and I pick Windows Boot manager from grub, Windows loads with 800x600 resolution and it is disabled in properties so that I cant change it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Intel Graphics driver along with nVidia in Windows fixed the issue. Actually I did this while trying to fix another issue where brightness control was not working in Windows - got the Intel drivers and installed it. That did fix the brightness control issue and as a bonus fixed the resolution issue with grub booting to Windows.

Comment: Please accept your answer as **answer**.